# Calculation of $\int\frac{e^{-\sin^2(x)}\tan^3(x)}{\cos(x)}dx=$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> $$\int\frac{e^{-\sin^2(x)}\tan^3(x)}{\cos(x)}\,dx=\text{?}$$

My work :
$$\int\frac{e^{-\sin^2(x)} \tan^3(x)}{\cos(x)} \, dx = \left\{\left(\int e^{-\sin^2(x)}\tan^3(x)\,dx\right)\frac{1}{\cos(x)}\right\}-\int\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)}\left(\int e^{-\sin^2(x)}\tan^3(x) \, dx\right)$$
where
$$\int e^{-\sin^2(x)} \tan^3(x)\,dx=\frac{e^{-\sin^2(x)}}{2\cos^2(x)}+c$$

Proof

\begin{align*}
\int e^{-\sin^2(x)}\tan^3(x) \,dx &=\int \frac{e^{-\sin^2(x)}(-\sin^2(x))(-2\sin(x)\cos(x)}{2\cos^4(x)}\,dx\\
&=\int \frac{e^{-\sin^2(x)}(-\sin^2(x))(\cos^2(x))^{'}}{2\cos^4(x)}dx\\
&=\int \frac{e^{\cos^2(x)-1}(\cos^2(x)-1)(\cos^2(x))^{'}}{2\cos^4(x)} \, dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int e^{t-1}\frac{t-1}{t^2} \, dt & (t=\cos^2(x))\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int e^{t-1}(\frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{t^2}) \, dt\\
&=\frac{1}{2} \left(\int \frac{e^{t-1}}{t}dt+\frac{e^{t-1}}{t}-\int \frac{e^{t-1}}{t} \, dt\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\frac{e^{t-1}}{t}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\frac{e^{\cos^2(x)-1}}{\cos^2(x)}+c
\end{align*}
So:
$$\int \frac{e^{-\sin^2(x)}\tan^3(x)}{\cos(x)}dx=\frac{1}{2} \frac{e^{\cos^2(x)-1}}{\cos^3(x)}-\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{e^{\cos^2(x)-1}\sin(x)}{\cos^4(x)} \, dx=\frac{1}{2} \frac{e^{\cos^2(x)-1}\sin(x)}{\cos^4(x)}-\frac{1}{2}J$$
where:
$$J=\int\frac{e^{\cos^2(x)-1}\sin(x)}{\cos^4(x)} \, dx$$

But I have not found a way to calculate $J$ after so many attempts
Any help please and thanks in advance

Comment: Try substituting y=cosx and then integrate by parts.

Comment: $$\begin{align} & \int\frac{e^{-\sin^2(x)}\tan^3(x)}{\cos(x)}\,dx \\ {} \\
= {} & \int \frac{e^{-\sin^2 x} \sin^2 x}{\cos^4 x} \big(\sin x \, dx\big) \\ {} \\
= {} & \int \frac{e^{-(1-\cos^2 x)} (1-\cos^2 x)}{\cos^4 x} \big( \sin x\, dx \big) \\ {} \\
= {} & \int \frac{e^{-(1-u^2)} (1-u^2)}{u^4}  (-du) \end{align}$$

Comment: @EricTowers : I've edited; see above. $\qquad$

Comment: Are you familiar with the [imaginary error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Imaginary_error_function)?

Comment: @Michael Hardy thanks Thanks for the editing and the idea

Comment: This question doesn't belong in "definite-integrals."  A definite integral is an integral over a set; this is an antiderivative.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u=\sec(x)$ to make

$$\int\frac{e^{-\sin^2(x)}\tan^3(x)}{\cos(x)}\,dx=\frac 1e\int e^{\frac{1}{u^2}} \left(u^2-1\right) \,du$$

$$\int e^{\frac{1}{u^2}}\,du=u\mathrm{e}^\frac{1}{u^2}-{\displaystyle\int}-\dfrac{2\mathrm{e}^\frac{1}{u^2}}{u^2}\,\mathrm{d}u$$
Let $v=\frac 1u$
$${\displaystyle\int}-\dfrac{2\mathrm{e}^\frac{1}{u^2}}{u^2}\,\mathrm{d}u=\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-1}{\sqrt{{\pi}}}}{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{2\mathrm{e}^{v^2}}{\sqrt{{\pi}}}\,dv=\sqrt{{\pi}}\operatorname{erfi}\left(v\right)=\sqrt{{\pi}}\operatorname{erfi}\left(\dfrac{1}{u}\right)$$

For $$\int u^2\,e^{\frac{1}{u^2}} \,du=-{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{v^2}}{v^4}\,dv$$ just continue with integrations by parts.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.

Let $t=\sin^2(x)$, then $$ \int\frac{e^{-\sin^2(x)}\tan^3(x)}{\cos(x)}\,dx=\int2 \dfrac{e^{-t}t^2 }{(1-t)^2}dt,$$
Let $1-t=-u$, then $$ \int\frac{e^{-\sin^2(x)}\tan^3(x)}{\cos(x)}= \int \dfrac{2e^{1-u}(1+u)^2}{u^2}du.$$
NB: Think about  $ \Gamma$ -function.